# OpenDaylight Geo-D setup

Tags: opendaylight, nitrogen

I am trying to set up `nitrogen` version of ODL in Geo-D configuration. As per the ODL documentation, initially I set up a cluster with 6 nodes(3 in active site and 3 nodes in standby site) with active side nodes' status as `Voting` members and Standby site nodes are as `non-voting` members.

My use case is - Bring down all the 3 nodes in active site and flip the voting state on standby nodes. There is a POST RPC call to flip the status.

```
POST  /restconf/operations/cluster-admin:flip-member-voting-states-for-all-shards
```

I am not able to execute this POST method through postman tool and getting authentication failure error.

> Error 401 Unauthorized

Answer (score 0):

are you able to execute the REST API before you bring down the active
nodes?

you can do a simple GET to /restconf/streams on all nodes when they are
up to double check. Should get a 200 response code and short/empty
streams json response.

Comment: Somehow I missed your reply to my question. Sorry for late response.  To answer your question, Yes I could able to flip the voting status when the nodes are up. In my testing, initially all the nodes are in "voting" status when all 6 nodes form a cluster. Then I flipped the voting status to "non-voting" in 3 standby nodes.